# Syntax error in redshift sql query with subqueries

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I'm quite new in SQL in general and haven't deal with redshift before. I'm trying to make one query, which works perfectly in postgresql. But I get syntax error in redshift. The query is:

```
SELECT 
    test.table_1.user_id as user_id,
    test.table_1.timestamp as start_session,
    test.table_1.step_3 :: timestamp +  interval '1 hour' as end_session,
    test.table_1.step_3 :: timestamp +  interval '1 hour' - test.table_1.timestamp :: timestamp as session_duration

FROM (SELECT *,
    min(case when page = 'second_page' then timestamp end) OVER (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as step_2,
    min(case when page = 'third_page' then timestamp end) OVER (partition by user_id order by timestamp desc rows between unbounded preceding and unbounded following) as step_3
    FROM test.table_1) test.table_1

WHERE 
    test.table_1.page = 'first_page' AND
    step_2 > test.table_1.timestamp AND
    step_3 > step_2 AND
    step_3 :: timestamp - step_2 :: timestamp < '1 hour' AND
    step_2 :: timestamp - test.table_1.timestamp :: timestamp < '1 hour'
ORDER BY
    user_id,start_session
```

The error is `Error running query: syntax error at or near "." LINE 11: FROM test.vimbox_pages) test.vimbox_pages ^`  in line  `FROM test.table_1) test.table_1`
I don't understand what's wrong there. 
By this query I'm trying to get session list of users actions during reading pages in some order. 
Will be thankful for any help!

Comment: Change the alias of the subquery from `test.table_1` to something like `t1` and use this in your query.

Comment: Documentation doesn't explicitly says that it also applies to aliases, but I guess alias naming should follow same rules: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_names.html
It says : **Contain no quotation marks and no spaces.**

Answer (score 0):

Aliases are identifiers and need to follow the rules for identifiers.  You can also simplify your query in other ways:

```
SELECT t.user_id, t.timestamp as start_session,
       (t.step_3::timestamp + interval '1 hour' as end_session),
       (t.step_3::timestamp + interval '1 hour' - t.timestamp::timestamp) as session_duration
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             MIN(CASE WHEN page = 'second_page' THEN timestamp END) OVER (PARTITION BY user_id) as step_2,
             MIN(CASE WHEN page = 'third_page' THEN timestamp END) OVER (partition by user_id) as step_3
      FROM test.table_1 t
     ) t
WHERE t.page = 'first_page' AND
      step_2 > t.timestamp AND
      step_3 > step_2 AND
      step_3::timestamp < step_2::timestamp + interval '1 hour' AND
      step_2::timestamp < timestamp + interval '1 hour'
ORDER BY user_id, start_session;
```

Notes:

- Your windowing clause is unnecessarily complex.  No `ORDER BY` is necessary if you want the entire window range.
- The conversions to `timestamp` should be unnecessary, given the names of the columns.  But I have left them in.
- `t.user_id as user_id` is redundant.  The column name is going to be `user_id` anyway.
- I don't ever see spaces around `::`.  Of course they are allowed, but the type conversion has very high precedence and is typically written without spaces.
- I prefer timestamp comparisons to timestamps, rather than converting to intervals.  Strange things can happen with intervals.